# Running a script to create tables with HSQLDB

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I use **hsqldb** to run my unit tests that need a database access.

For the moment, when I want to create a table for a specific test, I have the following code:

```
private void createTable() {
    PreparedStatement ps;
    try {
        ps = getConnection().prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE T_DATE (ID NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY, DATEID TIMESTAMP)");
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The `getConnection()` method retrieve a DataSource defined in a `Spring` context:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:memoryDB"/>
    <property name="username" value="SA"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
```

Now, I want to create my table from a SQL script (of course, this script will contain more than one table creation):

```
CREATE TABLE T_DATE_FOO (ID NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY, DATEID TIMESTAMP);
CREATE TABLE T_DATE_BAR (ID NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY, DATEID TIMESTAMP);
...
```

I've seen in the HSQLDB documentation that I can ask him to [run a script at the startup](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html#N107D5). However, it does not meet my requirements, as I want to run a script at the runtime.

Of course, I can read the file myself, and for every SQL statement, I run a `ps.executeUpdate()` command, but I don't want to use this kind of solution (except if there are no other solution).

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you're already using spring, you might want to use the [SimpleJdbcUtils.executeSQLScript](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/test/jdbc/SimpleJdbcTestUtils.html#executeSqlScript%28org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate,%20org.springframework.core.io.Resource,%20boolean%29) method which executes an SQL script where the statements are separated with semicolon.
this class is in the spring-test module (JAR).

Comment: This is working, thanks! However, I don't understand why Spring refuse to have a statement in several lines (even with a `;` at the end)...

Comment: which executeSqlScript method do you use ? there's a difference in implementation

Answer (score 4):

You might give `org.hsqldb.util.SqlFile` a try. This class seems to be a perfect match for your problem.

Comment: sqltool and SqlFile are not in Fedora hsqldb-2.4.0 package, and don't seem to be in the source.  It seems to be a separate product, perhaps with licensing incompatible with Fedora.

Comment: In the current version (hsqldb 2.7.2), the class SqlFile is in a different namespace org.hsqldb.cmdline. Also, full qualified class name is org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlFile. [Here](https://hsqldb.org/doc/verbatim/src/org/hsqldb/sample/SqlFileEmbedder.java) is an example of a program that loads/used a SQL file.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I do not know implications of this. I used it long time back it worked for me.
The SQLExec class is from ant.jar, you can probably look into the ant source to create your own utility class,

```
SQLExec sqlExec=new SQLExec();
sqlExec.setUserid("user");
sqlExec.setPassword("passowrd");
sqlExec.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname");
sqlExec.setDriver("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
sqlExec.setProject(new Project());
sqlExec.setSrc(new File("c:/test.sql"));
sqlExec.execute();
```

Comment: What would the ant file look like to simply initialize an hsqldb database from an sql script file?

I am building openas2 which uses maven, but I could add ant as a build requirement and run an ant file as part of installation.

Comment: I just used an actual ant build file, which worked perfectly to run arbitrary SQL to initialize the database:

https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/openas2/blob/master/f/hsqldb.xml

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I ended up splitting the text file by ; and executing each statement separately. It was OK because we had no inserts therefore no semicolons inside statements. I haven't found an easy way to run an SQL script at that time

Comment: In my case, splitting scripts will be easy, as the scripts are not really complicated and has no specific characters. However, I would really prefer a better solution if it exists...