# SimpleJdbcTestUtils.executeScript and multilines script

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, hsqldb

I want to load SQL script files for my unit tests. As I am using Spring 2.5.2, I [decided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295457/running-a-script-to-create-tables-with-hsqldb) to use the [`SimpleJdbcTestUtils.executeScript()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/test/jdbc/SimpleJdbcTestUtils.html#executeSqlScript%28org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate,%20org.springframework.core.io.Resource,%20boolean%29) method to load my script file, using the following code:

```
DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = ... // getting my DataSource defined in my Spring context
SimpleJdbcTemplate template = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/create-table.sql");
SimpleJdbcTestUtils.executeSqlScript(template, resource, true);
```

If I write each SQL statement in one line in the `create-table.sql` file, then everything is ok. But if I write a statement on multiple lines, then I get an error, even if the statement is finished by a `;`.

Working script :

```
CREATE TABLE T_FOO (ID NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY, DATEID TIMESTAMP, IS_ACTIVE INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE T_BAR (ID NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY, DATEID TIMESTAMP, IS_ACTIVE INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL);
```

Not working script:

```
CREATE TABLE T_FOO (
    ID NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY,
    DATEID TIMESTAMP,
    IS_ACTIVE INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE T_BAR (
    ID NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY,
    DATEID TIMESTAMP,
    IS_ACTIVE INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL);
```

Error on second file:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [CREATE TABLE T_FOO (]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token:  in statement [CREATE TABLE T_FOO (]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:404)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:519)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate.update(SimpleJdbcTemplate.java:237)
    at org.springframework.test.jdbc.SimpleJdbcTestUtils.executeSqlScript(SimpleJdbcTestUtils.java:150)
    at org.springframework.test.jdbc.SimpleJdbcTestUtils.executeSqlScript(SimpleJdbcTestUtils.java:113)
    at foo.bar.HsqldbUtils.run(HsqldbUtils.java:95)
    at foo.bar.SomeUnitTest.executeTests(SomeUnitTest.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.executeMethodBody(TestMethodRunner.java:99)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runUnprotected(TestMethodRunner.java:81)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runMethod(TestMethodRunner.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.run(TestMethodRunner.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.invokeTestMethod(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.run(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:35)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner$1.runUnprotected(TestClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner.run(TestClassRunner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token:  in statement [CREATE TABLE T_FOO (]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1UpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:509)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:393)
```

As I am willing to create more complex tables, I prefer to write the SQL instruction in a more readable way, so using several lines. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: WTF: http://efreedom.com/Question/1-2296468/SimpleJdbcTestUtilsexecuteScript-Multilines-Script ?

Comment: @Boris This site seems to have a copy of the SO question... Need some investigations about that. Thanks.

Comment: @Boris Look at this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58369 It seems OK then...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using Spring 2.5.2, but referring to the 2.5.6 documentation.

If you look at the javadoc for 2.5.2 (see [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.2/api/org/springframework/test/jdbc/SimpleJdbcTestUtils.html)), you'll note that it doesn't support multi-line scripts.

This was apparently resolved in 2.5.4 (issue [here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-4545)).

You should upgrade to 2.5.6, or better yet, 3.0.x.

Comment: You are totally right! I must update my bookmark or my Spring version indeed ;)